# Unable to use EOT inside if in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sshpass

Unable to use End of transmission (EOT) with ssh command inside if, it gives compilation error. I have tried using <<-EOT and <<<EOT but nothing worked. Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

```
#!bin bash

if [ -z "$2" ];
  then
    rsync -a abc.tgz root@$1:/var/folder1
    echo "Done upload"

    # Change permissions of agent image and create image configuration
    ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$1<<EOT
    chmod 644 /var;
    echo "image.id=$containerSha" > /var;
    EOT
else
    rsync -a abc.tgz root@$1:/var
    echo "Upload done"

    ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$1<<EOT
    cd /var;
    sshpass -p '$3' rsync -a abc.tgz root@$2:/var;
    sshpass -p '$3' ssh root@$2 'chmod 777 /var/*; ls -ltr';
    EOT
fi
exit
```

Comment: Your shebang on first line looks odd to me - you may not even be running `bash`

Comment: Per the `bash` tag you used - `For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting here.`.

Answer (score 3):

Running your script through [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) reveals these errors (along with a misshaped shebang line):

```
Line 12:
    EOT
^-- SC1039 (error): Remove indentation before end token
    (or use <<- and indent with tabs).
 
Line 21:
    EOT
^-- SC1039 (error): Remove indentation before end token
    (or use <<- and indent with tabs).
 
Line 23:
exit
    ^-- SC1072 (error): Here document was not correctly terminated.
    Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

The `EOT` markers must *not* be indented.

Comment: I believe you can indent EOT with tabs if you use `ssh ... <<-EOT` , i.e. with additional dash.

Comment: Yes, that's... what the error says.

Comment: Ahhh yeah! Didn't scroll over far enough on my small screen. You already have my vote

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue and removing indents will solves the problem:

Instead of:

```
...
    ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$1<<EOT
    chmod 644 /var;
    echo "image.id=$containerSha" > /var;
    EOT
else
...
```

You can try:

```
...
ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$1<<EOT
chmod 644 /var;
echo "image.id=$containerSha" > /var;
EOT
else
...
```

Answer (score -3):

If I'm not mistaken, an EOT is the character with the numeric value 4. If you define (for better readability) in your code

```
eot=$'\004'
```

you can later use `${eot}` to denote your end-of-transmission.

**UPDATE**: My answer here refers to the problem of representing the end-of-transmission character in a bash program. As AKX reasonably argued in his comment, the real question is unrelated to end-of-transmission, but on how to mark the end of a here-document.

Comment: `EOT` here is just the end-of-heredoc marker, it's not related to the character.

Comment: @AKX: In the **code** the OP does use the textual string `EOT`, but in the **question**, the OP asks explicitly for including and _End of Transmission_, which would be a character. That's why I thought he wants to use an ASCII EOT-code somehow, othewise it would not make sense to talk about _end of transmission_ in the first place.  Actually, he can use any charater sequence for his here-document, so why using this specific mentioning of an ASCII control character?

Comment: I'd guess they just googled EOT (since EOT tends to be in the examples for heredocs) and found that it can stand for End of Transmission.

Comment: @AKX : Sounds reasonable to me now. I clarified the misunderstanding in a comment. I was thinking to delete my answer, but it still might be helpful if someone searches SO for finding how to encode control characters in bash.